# IntelliJ: macOS CTRL+ARROW key is not working

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> is not being picked up inside IntelliJ when I switched to a new mac. When I go to keymap and try to enter <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> as key binding nothing new shows up. It used to work on my old mac.

IntelliJ: 15.0.5
OSX : 10.11.4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like it's already used by the system. Probably Mission Control? You may want to see if it is used in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and disable it there if necessary.

Comment: so useful! thanks! i looked everywhere for this problem and couldn't find the solution until i saw this :) btw this works also for PyCharm

Comment: Super useful !!! thank you so much . wasted so much time :).